# Calculate Road Distance for an array of longitude and latitudes

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, haversine

I have an Android app which captures lat-longs every 15 seconds and we use this bunch of lat-longs to find road distance between origin and destination (first and last lat-long sorted by time stamp).

Actually this app is for a client who runs mini trucks in the city and their truck drivers will be using this app to mark start/end of journey, drop of packets etc. We will be charging our client basis the km run during a trip.

In our scenario, vehicle will be delivering packets in colonies/small areas with full of turns, roundabouts and traversing same path again and again.

So I was trying to find a best way to calculate distance from all the collected lat-longs.

I opted two approaches:

1. Used "haversine" formula to calculate earth distance between two lat longs, add consecutive distances. Here I am getting 10% less distance.
2. Another is google map api but it is successful on straight roads and failing in my scenario.

Please suggest some approach which gives at least 96-97% accuracy which is industry wide accepted. We do not want to deploy VTS device in the vehicle as driver has to use Android app and it would double the cost.

Answer (score 1):

distanceTo() method will return you the distance as the bird flies, not by road. You can get the distance (by road) between two points using this method:

```
public String getDistance(final double lat1, final double lon1, final double lat2, final double lon2){
String parsedDistance;
String response;
    Thread thread=new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {

                URL url = new URL("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=" + lat1 + "," + lon1 + "&destination=" + lat2 + "," + lon2 + "&sensor=false&units=metric&mode=driving");
                final HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
                response = org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(in, "UTF-8");

                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                JSONArray array = jsonObject.getJSONArray("routes");
                JSONObject routes = array.getJSONObject(0);
                JSONArray legs = routes.getJSONArray("legs");
                JSONObject steps = legs.getJSONObject(0);
                JSONObject distance = steps.getJSONObject("distance");
                parsedDistance=distance.getString("text");

            } catch (ProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
thread.start();
try {
    thread.join();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return parsedDistance;
}
```

Comment: My question is that how can I get accurate distance for my own set of lat-longs or for a certain path, zig-zag with full of turns? I have already tried this solution as an option, mentioned in my question too.

Comment: As long as Google has it mapped, (its in a road and so on) it should work for you. If Google hasn't got your route mapped, I think there is no way to get a distance by road, as far as I know it.